# How to make a xl release fail gracefully

Tags: exception, groovy, xlrelease

I have xl release to accomplish for . It is having multiple phases and each phase is containing multiple tasks. There is a templet(orchestor) responsible for multiple application deployment. I want the scenario to achieve where even if one of the application release is failed the rest application will continue to get deployed.This whole process is getting done by a groovy script.

So basically i want a graceful way to handle the task failure in groovy for the xl realese.
the code goes like this:

```
if(condition)
{ 
throw new Exception("Build Failed as the TAF sanity or TAF consumer failed")
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: if(condition){
         throw new Exception("Build Failed as the TAF sanity or TAF consumer failed")
          
       
          }this exception i want to handle in more graceful way. So that the release will continue for other applications.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63188238/edit) the question

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a boolean variable to the release, for example `tafBuildSucceeded`. Set the variable to `false` by default and `true` when the build succeeds.

After the tasks completes, you can use the release variable in preconditions of subsequent tasks.